# Compare form component values

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a password confirmation form in React but I can't get the input validation to work both ways. To reproduce:

- Enter a password.
- Enter a matching confirmation password.
- Edit the confirmation password so it doesn't match anymore.
- Edit the password field to match the confirmation password.

The last step does not work and I think there's something wrong with the way I'm setting the password state in  `handlePasswordInput`. `this.state.password` in the `isConfirmedPassword` method does not hold the latest password when calling this method.

I've created a bin with the code: https://jsbin.com/sufupedayi/edit?js,output

Any React experts who can point me in the right direction?

```js
SignIn = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            password: null,
            confirmPassword: null
        }
    },
    handlePasswordInput(value) {
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.state.confirmPassword)) {
            this.refs.confirmPassword.validate(value);
        }

        this.setState({
            password: value
        })
    },
    handleConfirmPasswordInput(value) {
        this.setState({
            confirmPassword: value
        })
    },
    isConfirmedPassword(value) {
        return (value === this.state.password)

    },
    render() {
        return (
            <form autoComplete="off">
                <Input
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    errorMessage="Password is required"
                    onChange={this.handlePasswordInput}
                />
                <Input
                    ref="confirmPassword"
                    name="confirmPassword"
                    placeholder="Confirm password"
                    errorMessage="Passwords do not match"
                    onChange={this.handleConfirmPasswordInput}
                    validate={this.isConfirmedPassword}
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
});

Input = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            valid: false,
            value: null,
            errorMessage: this.props.errorMessage,
            errorVisible: false
        }
    },
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })

        if (this.props.validate) {
            this.validate(event.target.value);
        }

        if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
        }

    },
    validate(value) {
        if (this.props.validate && this.props.validate(value)) {
            this.setState({
                valid: true,
                errorVisible: false
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                valid: false,
                errorVisible: true
            });
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    name={this.props.name}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {!this.state.valid && <InputError errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage} visible={this.state.errorVisible} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

InputError = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var divStyle = {
            display: this.props.visible ? 'inline-block': 'none'
        }
        return (
            <div style={divStyle}>{this.props.errorMessage}</div>
        )
    }
})

React.render(<SignIn />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your handlePasswordInput with this. The reason it was happening was, your handlePasswordInput was being called before **password** was updated in the state. This does not happen when you were typing the confirm password field, because the **password** was already updated in the state.

Working fiddle - https://jsbin.com/cipuguxezi/1/edit?html,js,output

```
 handlePasswordInput(value) {
      this.setState({
         password: value
      });
      var self= this;
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        if (self.state.confirmPassword && self.state.confirmPassword.length) {
        self.refs.confirmPassword.validate(self.state.confirmPassword);
      }
    });

}
```

Note: There is some bug in JSBIN, please make sure

```
<div id="app"/>
```

is present above the script tag.

Comment: While this does works it doesn't feel like a proper solution. @Dominic-tobias's solution feels like a better one. His solution pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be and so you are already running into trouble with race conditions and hard to follow code. Try this instead:

```
var SignIn = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            password: null,
            valid: false
        }
    },

    checkRequired(value) {
        return !!value.trim();
    },

    checkPasswordsMatch(value) {
        var match = this.refs.password.getValue() === value;
        this.setState({
            valid: match,
            password: value
        });
        return match;
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <form autoComplete="off">
                <Input
                    ref="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    errorMessage="Password is required"
                    validate={this.checkRequired}
                />
                <Input
                    name="confirmPassword"
                    placeholder="Confirm password"
                    errorMessage="Passwords do not match"
                    validate={this.checkPasswordsMatch}
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
});

var Input = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            hasChanged: false,
            valid: false
        }
    },
    handleChange(event) {
        if (this.props.validate) {
            this.setState({
                valid: this.props.validate(event.target.value)
            });
        }

        this.setState({
            hasChanged: true
        });
    },

    getValue() {
        //return this.refs.input.value; // For React 0.14+
        return this.refs.input.getDOMNode().value;
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    ref="input"
                    name={this.props.name}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {this.state.hasChanged && !this.state.valid && <InputError errorMessage={this.props.errorMessage} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var InputError = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.errorMessage}</div>
        )
    }
})
```

e.g.
https://jsbin.com/febagojayo/edit?js,output

Comment: Indeed maybe a better approach but unfortunately this is not working. Validation is not working both ways. Editing the password field after a match does not show the error message.